# TYPO3 combine tx_news with powermail

Tags: typo3, tx-news, powermail

I made an event calendar with tx_news... On some events I want a "Register here" with a link to a site with powermail.

How can I do a prefill of the tx_news data in powermail?
I know how to do it with powermail/tx_news on the same page, but not on a different page.

Because the link to the register form is not on every event, I can't do a link with typoscript like this:

#### #

```
10 = COA
10.wrap = <div style="margin-top: 40px; text-align: right"><a style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); background-color: #4B2857; color: #FFF; text-align: center; padding: 10px 30px; border-radius: 20px;" href="/index.php?id=116|">Gleich anmelden</a></div>
10 {
          10 = TEXT
          10 {
            data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
            wrap = &tx_ttnews[tt_news]=|
            intval = 1
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
            insertData = 1
          }

        }
```

######

It should be easy for the editor to link the "Register here" in the RTE of tx_news...

Next solution would be a select field that is listening all "eventname, 00.00.0000" .. so, the user has to select the event again after clicking on "register here".

Comment: sorry, typoscript example is from a old tt_news project.. but I mean it for tx_news :)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with a powermail field type "typoscript" and this lib.news.
The only thing I can't is, that news in the archive aren't displayed.
I need a select where.. but I don't get it.

```
lib.news = CONTENT
lib.news.wrap = <label for="anlass">Anlass</label><div class="field-item" style="width: 100%; float: none; clear: both;"><select style="width: 100%" id="anlass"><option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>|</select></div>
lib.news {
  table = tx_news_domain_model_news
  select {
    pidInList = 81
    max = 10
    orderBy = uid ASC
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    wrap = |
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title
    10.crop = 50|...|1
    10.wrap = <option value="|">
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = datetime
    20.date = d.m.y
    20.noTrimWrap = || - |
    30 = TEXT
    30.field = title
    30.crop = 50|...|1
    30.wrap = |</option>
  }
}
```